# create copy paste example from dataframe or matrix in r

Tags: r

Quite often when trying to get help people ask for reproducible examples. Sometimes sharing a text file is not possible so I was wondering if there is a function which outputs the copy/paste command to recreate a dataframe or matrix with my data in r.

For example if I have this `matrix(3,3,3)` matrix I would like the output of the function to be something like this:

```
a <- data.frame(
    1 = c(3, 3, 3),
    2 = c(3, 3, 3),
    3 = c(3, 3, 3)
)
```

Comment: Use E.g. `dput`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ok, dput was exactly what I was looking for. Sorry, I don't know how I wasn't able to find it... Thanks!